# creating a non uniform distribution of points in 3D

Tags: matlab, math, graphics, computer-science, triangulation

I am trying to have a non-uniform and uniform distribution of points in 3D. Is there any way I can do so automatically? Do I use some sort of meshing software. I want it return a file stating the positions of the various points. Can some one help me out? And I also want this procedure to me repeatable for various number of points that I need. I want to start off with 100 then 200 , 300 etc..

Comment: What do you mean by a "a non-uniform and uniform distribution"?

Comment: I want a set of points that are at non uniform distances from each other ..

Comment: I assume you already know how to write the code for a uniform distribution? if not then you should limit your question first to that, or if so, you should limit your question to general non-uniform.

Answer (score 1):

Meshing also stores connectivity information along with coordinates. If you do not need connectivity, then generating just the coordinates with just an `x=rand(m,n,p)` function should satisfy your demands.